# Can you backup a local SQL Server database with a "BACKUP DATABASE" script?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, database-backups

**The problem is...**

I have a small windows form application running .NET 4.0 Framework and a local SQL Server 2012 database file to store the data (`.MDF` file). This database is not being used in relation with SQL Server and is being managed through the Visual Studio Server Explorer.

The task that I have is that I want to do backups on this database through the software itself or a service. I have looked around the internet and I have found that there is a script `BACKUP DATABASE [DatabaseName]`. I have tried running this against my local database and it says the database name is not recognized.

This is the code I have tried.

```
Private Sub btnBackup_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBackup.Click
    Dim FileName As String = Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmm") & ".bak"
    sfdBackupDB.InitialDirectory = txtBackupFolder.Text
    sfdBackupDB.FileName = FileName

    If sfdBackupDB.ShowDialog() <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
        If Not File.Exists(sfdBackupDB.FileName) Then
            SQLExecute("BACKUP DATABASE [ExampleDB] TO DISK = '" & sfdBackupDB.FileName & "' WITH FORMAT")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

1. `sfdBackupDB` is a save file dialog
2. `SQLExecute` is my own method to run a simple script but is literally just an SQL command call.

The error that I get from this goes:

> Database 'ExampleDB' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly. BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

There should be nothing wrong with the SQL Server connection that I am using as all other queries through the application are working so it can see the database is connecting to. Just in case it is important, the connection string is below:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database\ExampleDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

I have also found another method using SMO objects but I get pretty much the same outcome.

So my main questions are:

1. Is this type of backup possible with this type of database
2. Are there any better methods of doing it

Forgive my lack of knowledge but I have not had much experience with this type of local database as I have only really worked on SQL Server databases in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Verify that your database is actually called ExampleDB in the database server. The database name in the server can differ from the .mdf file name.

Comment: Since this database file isn't attached to a **server**, you cannot use `BACKUP DATABASE....` on it. One of the **many** drawbacks and shortcomings of using database **files** - you should really use a database **on the server** (as it was intended originally) and not fiddle around with free-flying database files... then you could use all the usual features and benefits of **SQL Server**

Comment: Yeh, I am regretting that choice now and I am currently in the process of porting it to SQL Server. Cheers